glmer singular fit after small change in the data
I'm running univariate analyses to search for biological factors related to my disease outcome. I am dealing with related individuals, meaning I am using glmer adjusting for covariates and family membership.
I would like to validate the findings from my discovery cohort (N=1000, % cases = 13%, N of groups = 750) in a replication cohort (N=350, % cases = 13%, N of groups = 250).
After doing this initially without any problems, I realised I had not accounted for use of a specific medication. Removal of those using this drug led to the remoal of 25 participants in my discovery and 6 in my replication.
I can re-run the analysis fine for the discovery dataset (results are pretty much unchanged), however, for the replication dataset I now get singular fits on almost every run.
I did not expect the removal of only 6 participants (50% of which were cases) to be so problematic. I would like to understand how this can be.
What I've looked at so far:

I wondered whether the number of males with my disease outcome may now be too small (since few males have the disease), however all of the participants I removed were females
I wondered whether removing these participants led to a loss of related individuals discordant for the outcome, thereby causing the variance of the random effects to be estimated at 0; yet, I only lose one discordant pair when I remove those using the medication
I compared the summary() of the models with and without the 6 participants removed due to medication use. The variance is indeed estiamted to be 0 without the 6 medication users, although I suspect something is wrong considering variance estimates are all sufficiently high in the models with the additional 6 participants (which ran without any warnings)
I randomly removed 6 samples (3 with my outcome and 3 without) and did not get the singularity issues, suggesting that it was not simply a question of reduced sample size (further supported by other experiments with the same dataset but fewer samples also running fine)

Here's the code with which I am running the models:
glmer(outcome ~ sex + age + bmi + independent_var + (1|family), data = data, family = binomial, control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)), nAGQ = 40)

I would like to know

why this is happening, despite such a small change in the data sample, and
if there's anything I can do to fix the problem?

